# Understand ramp color interpolation using QGIS 2.12

Tags: interpolation, tin, qgis-2.12, inverse-distance-weighted

I try to understand the color ramp in TIN and IDW interpolation. I work with height points layer. The low value in 8 and the highest value is 584. With the interpolation plugin i create TIN raster with Cellsize xy 5.

I get this raster:

[image]

and this is the color ramp:

[image]

This in the same point but with IDW interpolation:

[image]
[image]

when i choose random point (the blue point for example) 
[image]

in the TIN interpolation, i get this value:

[image]

and in the IDW interpolation, i get this value:

[image]

I don't understand:

1. Why there are differences in the color ramp between the two options?
2. What represent the value of some random point (not my layer points) when i use Identify Feature?
3. Why the color ramp don't include the minimum\maximum height point value?

Comment: Perhaps this documentation can shed some light on it for you: [Spatial Analysis (Interpolation)](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html)