# Understanding symbology in IDW interpolation using QGIS 2.18

Tags: symbology, interpolation, qgis-2.18, color-ramp, inverse-distance-weighted

Continuously to [Understand ramp color interpolation using QGIS 2.12](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197264/understand-ramp-color-interpolation-using-qgis-2-12), I used IDW interpolation on those height point without inserting the real values (minimum value is 8 meters, maximum value is 584 meters), and got the default ramp values:

[image]

But when I change manually the min\max values to the real ones, I get different interpolation:

[image]

I try to understand why the values and the symbology changed?

Answer (score 2):

The values for the raster result that was generated by the interpolation isn't actually changing--just the way it is being symbolized.

When you manually changed the min/max, your classification value levels, which determine how the raster is symbolized, also changed. The actual raster values, which is your interpolation result, aren't actually being changed.